# Can one reach the moon in World of Goo?

Tags: world-of-goo

Is that the purpose of the Goo Corp. tower?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Moon was supposed to be in the game, except due to time and design constraints it was never added.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Now that you mention it, I think I read that too in an interview. IIRC there even was a rumour that some console port would have it. Too bad it never was added :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No one's reached the moon in World of Goo yet, and there are some pretty amazing towers out there. It's safe to say you'll never reach the moon. The purpose of the World of Goo Corp. level is to create the largest tower you can.

Comment: And compete with other people's towers.